# how to turn off urllib/urllib2 response message?

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

I wrote a program in python to automatically retrieve info from website. But it returns a lot of respond messages, so I cannot see how my program processes. How can I turn it off?

**part of code**

```
cookiejar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
cookie_support = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookiejar)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(cookie_support, urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

....

url = 'http://weibo.com/2344328334/fans'
header = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36'}
req = urllib2.Request(url = url, headers = header)
result = urllib2.urlopen(req)
text = result.read()
```

**part of output**

```
send: 'GET /2344328334/fans HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: ...'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily\r\n'
header: Server: nginx
header: Date: Tue, 10 Sep 2013 03:54:02 GMT
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
header: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
header: Connection: close
header: Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
header: Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
... other messages ...
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the actual url, data, and headers that you sent so that it would be simpler to replicate your problem and test solutions.

Comment: I think this has something to do with urllib/urllib2 function. I don't want to interpret the response message, just want to turn it off. There's no print statement in my code, and it just prints itself out...

Comment: Right, but that doesn't happen every time that urlopen is called on any request.I tried it on a simple case and nothing was printed out. I think it's to some extent specific to the values that you've put in "url", "data", and "headers" (since the example values you gave won't actually run, I assume they aren't the ones you're using in your actual code). It's hard to test solutions to your problem if I can't make the problem happen in the first place.

Comment: Thanks! So this is interesting - even when I run that exact code I don't get anything printed out. What operating system and python version are you running?

Comment: Thanks. I found the problem. It's in HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1). It is in debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

You open the debug option, just remove the `debuglevel=1` 
And I recommand anather python http lib: [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) , It's very easy to use and powerful.Just install with `pip install requests` , support python2 and python3

It's [Feature Support](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/#feature-support) :

```
International Domains and URLs
Keep-Alive & Connection Pooling
Sessions with Cookie Persistence
...
```